# Como configurar el scroll en este slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hice este slider con jquery y greensock y necesito saber como puedo utilizar el scroll, creo que necesito usar el event mousewheel , pero no entiendo como configurarlo para poder usarlo en el slider ya que termino rompiendo todas las animaciones, alguien podria darme una mano para setear este problema

```js
(function($) {

 // Variables
 var sectionFrom,
  $slide = $('.slide'),
  $slideActive = $('.slide.active'),
  $navLink = $('.nav a'),
  $navLi = $('.nav li'),
  $body = $('body');

 // Init function
 function init(){

  // Set active slide visible
  TweenLite.set($slideActive, {x: '0%'});

  // Fade slides in
  TweenLite.set($body, {className: '-=loading'});

 }
 init();

 // Navigation click
 $navLink.on('click', function(e){
  if(e.preventDefault) {
   e.preventDefault();
  } else {
   e.returnValue = false;
  }  

  // prevent animation when animating
  if(!$body.hasClass('is-animating')){

   var sectionFrom = $('.slide.active'),
    sectionToID = $(e.target).attr('href'),
    sectionTo = $('div'+sectionToID);

   if(sectionFrom.attr('id') !== sectionTo.attr('id')){
    
    scrollToSection(sectionFrom, sectionTo);

   }

  }

 });

 function scrollToSection(sectionFrom, sectionTo){

  var heading = sectionTo.find('h1'),
   subheading = sectionTo.find('p'),
   bcg = sectionTo.find('.bcg'),
   bcgFrom = sectionFrom.find('.bcg'),
   tlDown = new TimelineLite({onComplete: setActiveSection(sectionFrom, sectionTo)}),
   tlUp = new TimelineLite();

  if(sectionFrom.index() < sectionTo.index()){

   //console.log('going down');
   tlDown
    .set($body, {className: '+=is-animating'})
    .to(sectionFrom, 1.2, {x: '-=100%', ease:Power4.easeInOut, clearProps: 'all'}, '0')
    .to(sectionTo, 1.2, {x: '0%', ease:Power4.easeInOut}, '0')
    .to(bcgFrom, 1.2, {x: '30%', ease:Power4.easeInOut, clearProps: 'all'}, '0')
    .from(bcg, 1.2, {x: '-30%', ease:Power4.easeInOut, clearProps: 'all'}, '0')
    .from(heading, 0.7, {autoAlpha: 0, x: 40, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, '-=1')
    .from(subheading, 0.7, {autoAlpha: 0, x: 40, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, '-=0.6')
    .set($body, {className: '-=is-animating'});

  } else {

   //console.log('going up');
   tlUp
    .set($body, {className: '+=is-animating'})
    .set(sectionTo, {x: '-100%'})
    .to(sectionFrom, 1.2, {x: '100%', ease:Power4.easeInOut, clearProps: 'all'}, '0')
    .to(sectionTo, 1.2, {x: '0%', ease:Power4.easeInOut}, '0')
    .to(bcgFrom, 1.2, {x: '-30%', ease:Power4.easeInOut, clearProps: 'all'}, '0')
    .from(bcg, 1.2, {x: '30%', ease:Power4.easeInOut, clearProps: 'all'}, '0')
    .from(heading, 0.7, {autoAlpha: 0, x: 40, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, '-=1')
    .from(subheading, 0.7, {autoAlpha: 0, x: 40, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, '-=0.6')
    .set($body, {className: '-=is-animating'});
  }

 }

 function setActiveSection(sectionFrom, sectionTo){

  // Add active class to the current slide
  sectionFrom.removeClass('active');
  sectionTo.addClass('active');

  // Add a body class highlighting the current slide
  $body.removeAttr('class').addClass($(sectionTo).attr('id')+'-active');

  // Highlight current slide in the navigation
  var currentSlideIndex = parseInt($(sectionTo).attr('id').slice(-2)) -1;
  $navLi.removeAttr('class');
  $navLi.eq(currentSlideIndex).addClass('active');

 }

})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  font: 16px/1.5 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #2e2e30;
  color: #fff;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.slidesContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
} 
.slideContent {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
}
.slideContent h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.slideContent p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    margin: 0;
}

/* =Project Slides */
.slide {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear, visibility 0.3s linear;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.loading {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.bcg {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    z-index: 1;
} 
.slide01 .bcg {
    background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/80/91/f9/8091f9dceb2ea55fa7b57bb7295e1824--hd-iphone--wallpapers-backgrounds-wallpapers.jpg');
}
.slide02 .bcg {
    background-image: url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/880665-road-wallpapers.jpg);
} 
.slide03 .bcg {
    background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/80/91/f9/8091f9dceb2ea55fa7b57bb7295e1824--hd-iphone--wallpapers-backgrounds-wallpapers.jpg');
} 
.slide04 .bcg {
    background-image: url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/880665-road-wallpapers.jpg);
} 
.slide04 .slideContent h1 {
    color: #222;
}
.slide04 .slideContent p {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

/* =Navigation */  
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
} 
.nav a {
    color: #222;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7) solid;
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.nav li:last-child a {
    border-width: 1px
}
.nav li.active a {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidesContainer">


            
            <div id="slide01" class="slide slide01 active">
                <div class="bcg"></div>
                <div class="slideContent">
                    <h1>Slide 1 Title</h1>
                    <p>This is a short description.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="slide02" class="slide slide02">
                <div class="bcg"></div>
                <div class="slideContent">
                    <h1>Slide 2 Title</h1>
                    <p>This is a short description.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="slide03" class="slide slide03">
                <div class="bcg"></div>
                <div class="slideContent">
                    <h1>Slide 3 Title</h1>
                    <p>This is a short description.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="slide04" class="slide slide04">
                <div class="bcg"></div>
                <div class="slideContent">
                    <h1>Slide 4 Title</h1>
                    <p>This is a short description.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#slide01">Slide 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#slide02">Slide 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#slide03">Slide 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#slide04">Slide 4</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: quieres que la transicion sea igual que pulsando botones, de uno en uno?

Comment: claro!, osea que se mantenga todo igual, pero agregandole el scroll

Comment: @coderpunky te deje una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentar algo parecido:

```
$('#foo').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
       $navLink.click(); /*UP*/
    } else {
       $navLink.click(); /*DOWN*/
    }
});
```

seria el handle de mousewheel, lo que no se como ese plugging detecta la direccion.